# QSslSocket error: Issuer certificate could not be found

Tags: ssl, apple-push-notifications, qsslsocket

I am developing an application on Windows which should connect to a server. Therefore I implemented a QSslSocket.

After the execution of the connection method the sslSocket errorString sends

> The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be
>   found. The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose.

The certificates are fine, but I couldn't explain why the connection isn't established. Does anybody has an idea how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to ignore the SSL error. So call `QSslSocket::ignoreSslErrors()` inside the slot which is emitted by the signal `sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)`.

Now it works fine.